# react native android gradle error react native reanimated

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin, react-native-reanimated

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
> Android gradle plugin: 7.4.2
> Gradle: 8.0.1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

ii am getting this error while trying to build apk of android

this is my distribution distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip

Comment: If the build failed with an exception, could you share the exception?